# How to find the maximum and minimum value of $2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

My try: Let $y$ =  $2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}$

1. Applying AM GM inequality I get 
   $y$ $> 2.2^{(\sin x+\cos x)/2}$. 
   Now, the highest value of R.H.S is $2^{\frac{\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}}$.

Should this mean that $y$ is always greater than $2^{\frac{ \left ( 2+\sqrt{2}\right ) }{2}}$?
But this is not true (we can see in the graph).

2. Calculus method:
   $dy/dx$ = $\ln\left(2\right){\cdot}{2}^{\sin\left(x\right)}\cos\left(x\right){-\ln\left(2\right){\cdot}{2}^{\cos\left(x\right)}\sin\left(x\right)}$

When $dy/dx$ =0,

$\tan x = 2^{\sin x- \cos x}$ and I am stuck here.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/p3zfvkq2mn

Comment: We have $y\ge 2\cdot 2^{(\sin x+\cos x)/2}$, with equality when $2^{\sin x}=2^{\cos x}$. **Minimize** $\sin x+\cos x$, and you will have minimized $y$. (We will want for example $x=3\pi/4$.)  So you have dealt with the minimum. Now tackle the maximum.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think it is the best process so far. For max $\sin x = \cos x=1/\sqrt2$ And for min $\sin x = \cos x=-1/\sqrt2$

Comment: I have written a fairly detailed outline for the *minimum*, based on your AM/GM calculation. That does not directly deal with the maximum.

Comment: Well, $y$ is maximum when $\sin x +\cos x$ is maximum so it deals with maximum too.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814830/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x},\;$ so $f^{\prime}(x)=(2^{\sin x}\cos x-2^{\cos x}\sin x)(\ln 2)$.

$\textbf{A)}$ To find the maximum of $f(x)$, it is enough to consider $f$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

$\;\;\;$Then $f(0)=3$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{2})=3$, and

$\;\;\;f^{\prime}(x)=0\iff 2^{\sin x}\cos x=2^{\cos x}\sin x\iff\frac{2^{\sin x}}{\sin x}=\frac{2^{\cos x}}{\cos x}\iff x=\frac{\pi}{4}$,

$\;\;\;$since if $\displaystyle g(t)=\frac{2^t}{t},\;$ $\displaystyle g^{\prime}(t)=\frac{2^t(t\ln 2-1)}{t^2}<0$ for $0< t<1$ so $g$ is 1-1 on $(0,1]$.

$\;\;\;$Since $f(\frac{\pi}{4})=2\cdot2^{\sqrt{2}/2}=2^{1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}>3,\;$ $f(\frac{\pi}{4})=2^{1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}$ is the maximum value.

$\textbf{B)}$ Similarly, to find the minimum of $f(x)$ it is enough to consider $f$ on $[\pi, \frac{3\pi}{2}]$.

$\;\;\;$Then $f(\pi)=\frac{3}{2}$ and $f(\frac{3\pi}{2})=\frac{3}{2}$, and  $f^{\prime}(x)=0\iff\frac{2^{\sin x}}{\sin x}=\frac{2^{\cos x}}{\cos x}\iff x=\frac{5\pi}{4}$

$\;\;\;$ since $\displaystyle g(t)=\frac{2^t}{t}$ is 1-1 on $[-1,0)$ as above.

$\;\;\;$Since $f(\frac{5\pi}{4})=2\cdot2^{-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}=2^{1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}<\frac{3}{2},\;\;$ $f(\frac{5\pi}{4})=2^{1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}$ is the minimum value.

Comment: Using the fact that $2^z/z$ is 1-to-1  for $0<|z|\le 1 which is readily shown by differentiating.

Answer (score 5):

Using AM GM inequality $$2^{\sin x} + 2^{\cos x} \ge2 \cdot2^{\frac{\sin x + \cos x}2}$$

Now the the minimum value i.e., equality occurs if $2^{\sin x} = 2^{\cos x}\iff \sin x = \cos x$

$\implies \tan x = 1 \implies \sin x = \cos x = \pm \dfrac1{\sqrt2}$

So, the minimum value $$= 2^{1 -\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}$$

Set $y=\pi+x$ to find the maximum value.

Comment: But this should lead to minimum value, right? However this is the maximum value

Comment: To find the maximum value, you might want to study $y^2$ (which attains max/min at the same points as $y$) and then use the AM GM inequality on the product term.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, This the minimum value. Now check the updated answer

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $ y=π+x$ ?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, As that makes  $\sin y=-\sin x,\cos y=-\cos x$

Comment: I still don't get it. Why do I need $\sin y$ and $\cos y$. Did you mean $x(new) =x(old) + \pi$?

Comment: I would really like it if you could elaborate a little more on the maximum. I still don't see an easy way out.

Comment: The LHS and RHS of the AGM inequality agree only when the two terms on the LHS are equal to each other but this doe not imply that this occurs when the LHS value is extremal.Otherwise we could say that the extremal values of f(x)+g(x) always occur when f(x)=g(x) for any positive functions f,g.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(u,v)=2^u+2^v;\;$ we want to find the extrema of $f$ on the circle $u^2+v^2=1$.

Using Lagrange multipliers, $\;\;2^u\ln2=\lambda(2u)$ and $2^v\ln 2=\lambda(2v)\;$ so $\;\displaystyle\frac{2^u\ln2}{2u}=\frac{2^v\ln2}{2v}$.

Then $\displaystyle\frac{2^u}{u}=\frac{2^v}{v}$ and therefore $u=v$,

$\;\;\;$since the function $\displaystyle g(t)=\frac{2^t}{t}$ is 1-1 on $[-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$

$\;\;\;$because $\displaystyle g^{\prime}(t)=\frac{2^t(t\ln 2-1)}{t^2}<0$ for $t\in(-1,0)\cup(0,1)$.

Then $u^2+v^2=1\implies 2u^2=1\implies u=v=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Thus $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)=2^{1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}$ is the maximum, and $\displaystyle f\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)=2^{1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}$ is the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Write $x:={\pi\over4}+t$, and put ${\displaystyle{1\over\sqrt{2}}\log 2}=:\lambda\doteq0.490$. Then
$$2^{\cos x}+2^{\sin x}=2 e^{\lambda\cos t}\>\cosh(\lambda\sin t)=: g(t)\ .$$
Since $g$ is a smooth $2\pi$-periodic function its global extrema are at the zeros of its derivative
$$g'(t)=2\lambda e^{\lambda\cos t}\bigl(-\sin t\>\cosh(\lambda\sin t)+\cos t\>\sinh(\lambda\sin t) \bigr)\ .$$
When $\cos t=0$ one necessarily has $g'(t)\ne0$. We may therefore consider the equation
$$\tan t=\tanh(\lambda \sin t)\ .\tag{1}$$
For $0< t<{\pi\over2}$ one has $$\tanh(\lambda \sin t)<\lambda\sin t<t<\tan t\ .$$
Symmetry considerations then imply that $t=0$ and $t=\pi$ are the only solutions of $(1)$ mod $2\pi$. Therefore
$$\bigl\{g(0), g(\pi)\bigr\}=\{2e^\lambda, 2e^{-\lambda}\}=\bigl\{2\cdot 2^{1/\sqrt{2}}, \> 2\cdot 2^{-1/\sqrt{2}}\bigr\}$$
are the maximal and the minimal value of $g$, and whence of $2^{\cos x}+2^{\sin x}$, on ${\mathbb R}$.