# Minimum value of $2^{\sin x} + 2^{\cos x}$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

> Find the minimum value of $2^{\sin x} + 2^{\cos x}$.

---

I tried using AM-GM inequality,

$$\frac{2^{\sin x} + 2^{\cos x}}2 ≥ \sqrt{2^{\sin x} 2^{\cos x}}\\
2^{\sin x} + 2^{\cos x} ≥ 2^{\frac{\sin x + \cos x}2+1}\\$$

This equality holds for $x=\fracπ4$, so I get $2^{\sin x} + 2^{\cos x} = 2^{1 + \frac 1{\sqrt2}}$.

But the minimum is $2^{1-\frac1{\sqrt2}}$.

---

Edit: I should have considered  $x=\frac{5π}4$

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1449907/42969

Comment: Compare with $e^{-x^2}\ge e^{-2x^2}$. Equality holds just for $x=0$, but this doesn't prevent them from being both smaller than their value at $x=0$ somewhere else, while still being one larger than the other.

Comment: I got it... Thanks :)